# Setting up my www directory correctly

Tags: webserver, nginx, www

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

I need to create a my `www` directory (in `/home`) and set the permissions/ownership correctly so that any new files and directories created by myself (via terminal etc, username is `matt`) OR the web server (Nginx in this case) are owned by `matt:www-data`. I believe I need to do something with `setfacl` but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For setting www, I usually set ownership first, in this case I use your username 'matt' and the directory that I use `/var/www/`. Make sure that your username is member of www-data group, if not, you can add  `sudo adduser matt www-data`

```
sudo chown matt:www-data -R /var/www
```

The second thing, we should set permission

```
sudo chmod 0755 -R /var/www
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, it was enough to set the read flag on the files you want your web server to be able to display and open.